# separating audio layer and video from YouTube

Tags: javascript, audio, video, iframe, youtube

Can I separate audio layer and video from YouTube and add only audio to my website? I want to create app like spotify but I want to play music for example from YouTube

Comment: Shot answer is that you can't -  it's against YouTube terms of use. And that's just making the tool. Once you let another individual (even if just one person) listen or otherwise access to the media it becomes a matter of copyright infringement. Tread with caution with this idea

Answer (score 0):

Use YouTube-dl to download the audio streams. You could probably stream them too in real time if you were fancy.